# button to clear all select fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, button, reset

```
 <form method="post" action="asdasd" class="custom" id="search">
 <select name="sel1" id="sel1">
   <option value="all">all</option>
   <option value="val1">val1</option>
   <option value="val2" selected="selected">val2</option>
 </select>
 <select name="sel2" id="sel2">
   <option value="all">all</option>
   <option value="val3">val3</option>
   <option value="val4" selected="selected">val4</option>
 </select>
 </form>
```

I want to select the first field of all the Select (so set the value "all" to all the Select) clicking a button

Comment: Have you made any attempts to solve this yourself? It kind of looks like you're asking us to do your work for you...

Comment: SO helps you to share problems with others not for asking others to done your work

Answer (score 1):

Your form should have a reset button

```
<form method="post" action="asdasd" class="custom" id="search">
 <select name="sel1" id="sel1">
   <option value="all">all</option>
   <option value="val1">val1</option>
   <option value="val2" selected="selected">val2</option>
 </select>
 <select name="sel2" id="sel2">
   <option value="all">all</option>
   <option value="val3">val3</option>
   <option value="val4" selected="selected">val4</option>
 </select>
 <input type="button" name="Reset" />
 </form>
```

After adding a reset button input element to your form below code should reset all select fields.

```
jQuery( "input[name=Reset]" ).click( function(){ //jQuery click event
jQuery( "select" ).each(function() {     //for each select type
    $(this).val( "all" );
});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add attribute `selected` to the first option of all select box.

```
$("select option:first").attr('selected','selected');
```

See [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o6zu12j6/)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use jquery. This can be done by JavaScript

```
  document.getElementById("sel1").selectedIndex = 0;
```

Here is my [JSFiddler demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w5qjvxte/2/) for complete code.

This is jQuery way to achieve above

```
  $("select").val("0");
```

Or to be more specific

```
  $("#sel1 , #sel2").val("0");
```